# Enumerate NSMutableArray of buttons adding some to another NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

This seems simple enough but I just end up with an empty array.

I want to take a pressed button, find all the buttons that are a next to it (see comments in code), and add all of those found buttons to another NSMutableArray.

Then I want to loop through that array and do something with each button.

Inthe below im using `[caualtiesArray addObject: btn];` to store the found buttons in the array but it does not seem to be doing that and I cant figure out why.

```
-(void)detonateBomb:(UIButton*)bombDetonated{
    //stop the spiketimers first
    [spikeTimer invalidate];
    [removeSpikeTimer invalidate];
    //move bomb button (non enabled and hidden) over the pressed button
    //really we are just going to use its rect to find buttons next
    //to the bomb since its rect is lage enough to overlap the others
    bombRadius.center=bombDetonated.center;
    //create an array to hold any matches
    //we cant use the original arrary
    //because the array would be mutated while
    //its being enumerated
    NSMutableArray *caualtiesArray;
        //I did try moving this to declare caualtiesArray
        //in the .h....which didnt fix the issue
    //loop through all of the unpopped buttons
    //if any intersect with "bombRadius" they are next to the bomb
    //add them to the array
    for(UIButton *btn in mutableBubbleArray){
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(btn.frame, bombRadius.frame)) {
            [caualtiesArray addObject: btn];
            //^^This seems to be the problem
            NSLog(@"------- added button: %ld", (long)[btn tag]);
            NSLog(@"------- foundButtons: %ld", (long)[caualtiesArray count]);
            NSLog(@"*******");
        }
    }
    //now that we have them all
    //pop them and add an extra 50 pts each
    //lets see how many we have first though
    NSLog(@"------- foundButtons: %ld", (long)[caualtiesArray count]);
    for(UIButton *foundBtn in caualtiesArray){
            score+=50;
            [self popBubble:foundBtn];
        NSLog(@"------- popping button: %ld", (long)[foundBtn tag]);
        NSLog(@"*******--------------------");
    }
    //add an extra 100 pts
    score+=100;
    //move the bomb back off-screen
    bombRadius.center=CGPointMake(-100, -100);
    //clean the array
    [caualtiesArray removeAllObjects];
}
```

And this is what I get in the console:

```
2014-01-15 00:25:39.331 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- (pop method)POPPED A BOMB
2014-01-15 00:25:39.333 TestApp[7324:60b] *********************************
2014-01-15 00:25:39.335 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- added button: 28
2014-01-15 00:25:39.337 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- foundButtons: 0
2014-01-15 00:25:39.339 TestApp[7324:60b] *******
2014-01-15 00:25:39.341 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- added button: 29
2014-01-15 00:25:39.342 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- foundButtons: 0
2014-01-15 00:25:39.345 TestApp[7324:60b] *******
2014-01-15 00:25:39.347 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- added button: 39
2014-01-15 00:25:39.350 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- foundButtons: 0
2014-01-15 00:25:39.352 TestApp[7324:60b] *******
2014-01-15 00:25:39.354 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- added button: 40
2014-01-15 00:25:39.355 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- foundButtons: 0
2014-01-15 00:25:39.357 TestApp[7324:60b] *******
2014-01-15 00:25:39.358 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- added button: 41
2014-01-15 00:25:39.360 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- foundButtons: 0
2014-01-15 00:25:39.361 TestApp[7324:60b] *******
2014-01-15 00:25:39.363 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- added button: 52
2014-01-15 00:25:39.364 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- foundButtons: 0
2014-01-15 00:25:39.366 TestApp[7324:60b] *******
2014-01-15 00:25:39.367 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- added button: 53
2014-01-15 00:25:39.368 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- foundButtons: 0
2014-01-15 00:25:39.370 TestApp[7324:60b] *******
2014-01-15 00:25:39.371 TestApp[7324:60b] ------- foundButtons: 0
```

Obviously, finding the buttons works fine but they are not being added to the new array> I just dont understand why. This seems like it should work.

Comment: `NSMutableArray *caualtiesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` before use.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you didn't init caualtiesArray.

`caualtiesArray = [NSMutableArray array];`

Comment: ah! before i'd only use them like: `mutableBubbleArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:bubble1,bubble2, bubble3,nil];` Didnt realize I had to init when creating an empty array. Works perfect now!